# PHP Eclipse cannot open local PHP file!

Tags: php, eclipse

I click on file, select to open it with Eclipse, Eclipse opens but the file is not showing. Just empty Eclipse. Manual opening via 'File->Open file' works. Also when I want to open remote file via Filezilla (files are on a remote ftp server), Eclipse opens as well but the file is not loaded. I use Eclipse PHP, Helios Release, Build id: 20100617-1415.

I also tried to install Zend, but it did not solve the issue.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: It seems that it open only if Eclipse is already started. But if Eclipse isn't started, the file will no be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open file with eclipse by using "Open with" in windows file context menu. You must open eclipse first then drag your file or use open file function in eclipse. The reason I think is eclipse is not resolve the command line option for opening a file.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Helios, you can, but it requires some hacking. See [this article](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature) for more details.

BTW, some Eclipse distributions already have this feature. From my experience, Zend Studio (latest beta) supports this.

Comment: well, all of this sound fine, but it DOES NOT work. Which system do you have?

Comment: I'm primarily on Mac OS X. I did test it a bit on Windows and found that it needs some registry tweaking. I'm pretty sure it worked to some extent. I was on XP.